# C++ XOR swap on float values

Tags: c++, floating-point, swap, xor

Is it possible to use XOR swapping algorithm with float values in c++?

However wikipedia says that:

> XOR bitwise operation to swap values of distinct variables having the same data type

but I am bit confused. With this code:

```
void xorSwap (int* x, int* y) {
   *x ^= *y;
   *y ^= *x;
   *x ^= *y;
}

int main() {

   float a = 255.33333f;
   float b = 0.123023f;
   xorSwap(reinterpret_cast<int*>(&a), reinterpret_cast<int*>(&b));
   std::cout << a << ", " << b << "\n";

   return 0;
}
```

it seems to work (at least under gcc), but I am concerned if such a practice is allowed if needed?

Comment: Remember that the data for your floating point variables are stored as just zeroes and ones, just like any other data and values on a binary computer. Operating on the bits will work just the same, no matter what those bits represents.

Comment: What's the problem? Your quote from Wikipedia says that it _is_ possible, and it's right because of what @Someprogrammerdude said :D

Comment: Please don't use the `xor` trick. It's useless unless you're so short of memory that you can't afford an extra integer (and even modern embedded systems have bucketloads of memory), and it's probably *slower* than a simple temp variable swap. It should be relegated to the days of us old folk who still fondly remember tring to cram their code into a 1K ZX80 :-)

Comment: yes, bits is bits, doesnt matter what they represent, pointers, float, etc.  The trick here is accurately and completely converting the float bits to integer bits and back.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks :) why it's probably slower?

Comment: Accessing data through a pointer to a different, unrelated type is undefined behavior. Or am I missing some new development in the C++ standard?

Comment: @IInspectable I dont think you missed anything. The OP's technique is not guranateed by the standard; it highly depends on architecture and implementation. For the least, who said that a `float` and an `int` always have the same size and alignment!?

Comment: @m.zygmunt Six memory accesses and three xors is probably slower than four memory accesses and no xors. (This trick is a space, not speed, optimisation.)

Comment: Aside from questions of whether this works in general, try swapping a value with itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, what you ask *is* possible but, as clearly commented by IInspectable, it causes UB (Undefined Behaviour).
Anyway, I do suggest you to use [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) instead, it's a template often specialized for specific data types and designed to do a good job.

Comment: §3.10 p 10 [basic.lval]: *"If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undeﬁned: [...]"* - So, yes, possible, plausible, clean. And wrong. This is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't cause undefined behaviour.  It simply cannot, the algorithm is independent of the binary interpretation of the information swapped.  The byte patterns are swapped the same as would be through assignments.  We are going too far with the UB issue, I'm afraid. it's like saying that transmitting a bit pattern through a comms line makes undefined behaviour, as bits in a float are send as bits and not as a double.

Answer (score 1):

If `int` is the same size as `float`, it is going to work in practice on any reasonable architecture. The memory in the float is a set of bits, you interpret those bits and swap them completely using xor operations. You can then use Those bits as the proper `float`s again. The quote you refer to only says that the two values you swap need to be of the same type, and both are `int`s.

However, on some architectures, this can result in a movement between different sorts of registers, or explicitly flushing registers to memory. What you will see on almost any sane architecture with a sane optimizing compiler these days, is that an explicit swap, using `std::swap` or an expression with a temporary variable, is in fact faster.

I.e. you should write:

```
float a = 255.33333f;
float b = 0.123023f;
float tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;
```

or preferably:

```
float a = 255.33333f;
float b = 0.123023f;
std::swap(a,b);
```

If the standard library author for your architecture has determined xor swapping to indeed be beneficial, then you should hope that the last form will use it. xor swapping is a typical bad idiom in terms of hiding intent in an unneccesarily arcane implementation. It was only ever efficient in seriously register-starved cases with bad optimizers.

Comment: The xor-trick would also fail if int and float had the same size, but int had a stricter alignment requirement. I admit that it is unlikely.

Comment: @HansOlsson: To the contrary, with dedicated FPU circituitry, different alignment requirements between floating point types and integer types are more likely than not. All the more since FPU calculations are often performed in SIMD units, that do require alignment usually different from that for the general purpose CPU registers.

Comment: @IInspectable The special SIMD units is likely to have a stricter alignment for floats, but the problem with xor-trick only occurs if the alignment-requirement for int is stricter.

Answer (score 1):

Your code there invokes undefined behavior. It's not legal in C or C++ to cast a `float*` to a `int*` and use it as such. `reinterpret_cast` should be used to to convert between unrelated structs with compatible layouts, or to temporarily convert between a typed pointer and `void*`.

Oh, and in this particular case the UB is not of merely academic concern. A compiler may notice that `xorSwap()` doesn't touch any `float`s, perform optimizations allowed to it by the aliasing rules of the language, and print out the original values of `a` and `b` instead of the swapped values. And that's not even getting into architectures where `int` and `float` are of different sizes or alignments.

If you wanted to do this safely, you'd have to `memcpy()` from your floats into unsigned char arrays, do the XOR in a loop, then `memcpy()` back. Which would of course make the operation slower than a normal swap. Of course, xor-based swapping is ALREADY slower than normal swapping.

Comment: " `reinterpret_cast` should be used to to convert between ... a typed pointer and void* ". Wouldn't you use `static_cast` for that?

Comment: @user2079303 The two have equivalent functionality in that situation, but I tend to prefer `reinterpret_cast`, just because it looks scary to a level appropriate to the situation. Of course, it's pretty rare to use `void*` in C++ in the first place, so the question doesn't often come up.

Answer (score 1):

It is:

a) possible when the compiler allows it.

b) an operation for which the standard does not define behaviour (i.e. undefined behaviour)

c) on gcc, actually less efficient than stating exactly what you want:

given:

```
void xorSwap (unsigned int* x, unsigned int* y) {
   *x ^= *y;
   *y ^= *x;
   *x ^= *y;
}

void swapit3(float& a, float&b)
{
  xorSwap(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&a), reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&b));
}
```

results in this:

```
swapit3(float&, float&):                         # @swapit3(float&, float&)
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        xor     eax, dword ptr [rsi]
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], eax
        xor     eax, dword ptr [rsi]
        mov     dword ptr [rsi], eax
        xor     dword ptr [rdi], eax
        ret
```

whereas this:

```
void swapit2(float& a, float&b)
{
  std::swap(a,b);
}
```

results in this:

```
swapit2(float&, float&):                         # @swapit2(float&, float&)
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi]
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], ecx
        mov     dword ptr [rsi], eax
        ret
```

link: https://godbolt.org/g/K4cazx